# Как убрать добавление "события" для компонента в конструкторе, при двойном щелчке или

Tags: c#, winforms, события, click

При кликанье по кнопкам, текстбоксам может случиться двойной клик и вот в ваш чистый код помещается наглое "событие" а ля 
`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` 
Как изменить эту "горячую клавишу мыши" на -"изменить текст элемента", или хотя бы выключить ее?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8439171/276994